# Two variables normal distribution

Tags: r, plot, normal-distribution

Would someone help me to get a 3d plot for two variables normal distribution in R using persp function? I'm using mvtnorm package and it's a bit confusing...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is highly vague. Please specify what you want to plot.

Comment: A plot for a **sample** two variables normal distribution using mvtnorm.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, it seems you would like something like this:

```
show.2dnorm <- function(n, mean = rep(0, nrow(sigma)), sigma = diag(length(mean))) {
  require(mvtnorm)
  require(ggplot2)
  norm2d <- as.data.frame(rmvnorm(n, mean, sigma))
  colnames(norm2d) <- c('x', 'y')
  ggplot(norm2d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
}

# standard normal
show.2dnorm(1e4, c(0, 0))
# 0.6 correlation
show.2dnorm(1e4, sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.6, 0.6, 1), 2))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you please give me help to create 3d plot using persp function?

Comment: This would require a bit different approach. It is probably a good idea to leave this question as it is, while you can open another question with a detailed requirement.